# Store word from $zero address to register $t1

Tags: mips

What would be the result of this MIPS store word instruction which references the $zero register and writes to register $t1

```
sw $t1, 50($zero)
```

Comment: Why not just run it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

`sw $ra, offset($rb)` will store the value $ra to the address [$rb + offset]. In this case $rb = $zero so it becomes direct addressing

That means the instruction will store $t1 to the memory address 50

```
[50] = $t1
```